# Upgrading SmartGWT LGPL from 5 to 6 problems

Tags: javascript, gwt, smartgwt

I recently tried to update my rather complex application from 5 to 6 (`LGPL`, `6.0-p20160713`, `isc.version:` `"v11.0p_2016-07-13/LGPL Development Only"`) and unfortunately it breaks while loading in all 3 browsers (IE, FireFox, Chrome). I also have a sample project with very minimal setup to test various features of smartgwt and it upgraded from 5 to 6 without any problems. So it must be something with the setup of my application. For start I should mention that I have multiple times cleaned the browser cache without success. To the point now.
My application breaks while loading with the following errors appearing on the javascript console:

[image]

My gwt.xml file

```
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.6.1//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.6.1/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
    <inherits name="com.my.application.Application"/>
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
    <inherits name='com.smartgwt.SmartGwtNoScript' />
    <inherits name='com.smartgwt.tools.SmartGwtTools' />
    <inherits name="gwtupload.GWTUpload" />
    <inherits name="com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.gwt-log-${gwt-log.level}" />
    <inherits name="com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.gwt-log-RemoteLogger" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.inject.Inject"/>
    <inherits name="org.fusesource.restygwt.RestyGWT" />
    <inherits name="com.my.application.module.NewModule" />
    <inherits name='com.pleft.SmartCKEditor' />

    <set-property name="compiler.stackMode" value="emulated"/>
    <set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordLineNumbers" value="true"/>
    <set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordFileNames" value="true"/>  

    <stylesheet src="css/Upload.css" />
    <stylesheet src="css/draggable.css" />
    <stylesheet src='Application.css' />
    <set-property name="user.agent" value="${gwt.user.agent}" />

    <set-property name="log_GWTLogger" value="DISABLED" />
    <set-property name="log_SystemLogger" value="DISABLED" />
    <set-property name="log_DivLogger" value="DISABLED" />

    <source path="client" />
    <source path="shared" />
    <entry-point class='com.my.application.client.EntryPoint' />
</module>
```

It looks like the `isc` js object is not initialized correctly or fully. In the js console I can see that it exists, however it is missing e.g. the `Page` object or the `Log` object.

Reverting to SmartGWT version 5 and everything works like a charm. Can anybody provide some insight here? thanks!

**EDIT**:

My Application.html bootstrap file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
        <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
        <title>Odyssey</title>

        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/datepicker.css">

        <script src="js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/scriptaculous.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/cropper.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/CropImageManager_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="com.my.application.Application.nocache.js"></script>
        <script> var isomorphicDir = "sc/";</script>
        <script src="sc/initsc.js"></script>
        <script src="sc/modules/ISC_Core.js"></script>
        <script src="sc/modules/ISC_Foundation.js"></script>
        <script src="sc/modules/ISC_Containers.js"></script>
        <script src="sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js"></script>
        <script src="sc/modules/ISC_Forms.js"></script>
        <script src="sc/modules/ISC_RichTextEditor.js"></script>
        <script src="sc/modules/ISC_Calendar.js"></script>
        <script src="sc/modules/ISC_DataBinding.js"></script>
        <script src="sc/skins/Enterprise/load_skin.js"></script>
        <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You inherit `<inherits name='com.smartgwt.SmartGwtNoScript' />` so without scripts. Then you have to manually add the js files to the HTML. If the js files exist you seem to do this, but please once check with `<inherits name='com.smartgwt.SmartGwt' />`.

Comment: @mxlse Thanks my friend, I do import the js files in my Application.html bootstrap file. I will also upload it here for completeness sake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit. For some reason the inclusion of js scripts irrelevant to GWT and SmartGWT caused this malfunction.

```
<script src="js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/scriptaculous.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/cropper.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/CropImageManager_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I removed the lines including those scripts in `Application.html` since my application didn't use them anymore (they were leftovers from previous versions) and now it compiles and runs fine.